# How to Vertically Center an img in the logo in this navigation-bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

[**JSFiddle here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/71/)

As you can see in the given SSCCE, the image in the logo does NOT align well with the text next to it. I need that `<img>` and adjacent `<span>` perfectly, so that they are *vertically-middle-aligned* rather than sharing the same baseline.

I have this:

[image]

and I need this:

[image]

**So how do I do that?**

Giving `vertical-align:middle;` to `.brand-logo` or `.brand-logo > img` or  both `.brand-logo > img` and `.brand-logo > span` did Not help.

Adding class `valign-wrapper` to `a.brand-logo` or `div.nav-wrapper` also did not help. ([source](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html))

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="black">
 <div class="nav-wrapper">

  <a class="brand-logo center brown-text text-lighten-4" href="#"><img alt="" src="https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/wordpress-logo-simplified-rgb.png" width="40px" height="40px" class="responsive-img" />
   <span>BRAND</span>
  </a>

 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: redundant question, seek for vertical-align and apply img, span {vertical-align:middle;} https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/72/

Comment: @GCyrillus Like I mentioned in the second-last line, that did Not help!

Comment: @Sie it works in the JSFiddle for me! Along with modifying the Stack Snippet.

Comment: what about the jsfiddle ? where does it go wrong? please clarify :)

Comment: are you still around ? @Sie see with borders to see where each are standing https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/74/ where is that going wrong for you ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Sorry. I needed to clean my browser's cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `vertical-align: middle;` to both `span` and the `image` .Try this

```
span,img{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.brand-logo > span,.brand-logo > img{
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="black">
 <div class="nav-wrapper">

  <a class="brand-logo center brown-text text-lighten-4" href="#"><img alt="" src="https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/wordpress-logo-simplified-rgb.png" width="40px" height="40px" class="responsive-img" />
   <span>BRAND</span>
  </a>

 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox and vertical alignment should do the trick.

```css
.brand-logo.center.brown-text.text-lighten-4 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="black">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">

    <a class="brand-logo center brown-text text-lighten-4" href="#"><img alt="" src="https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/wordpress-logo-simplified-rgb.png" width="40px" height="40px" class="responsive-img" />
      <span>BRAND</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</nav>
```