# Remove vertical space between two elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following `HTML` and my objective is to show the image and the text in the same line, vertically and horizontally aligned. Here is the `CSS` I used:

```css
* {
    background-color: #1B262C;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.logo {
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo-img {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo-text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 96px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>(...)</head>
    <body>
        <header class="logo">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="Sigma logo" class="logo-img">
            <h1 class="logo-text">Sigma</h1>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

The borders are for visualization only. With these files, the following output is produced:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcAi5.png)

Please note the strange vertical space that appears above the image. How can I remove it, and effectively align the text and the image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Vertically Center an img in the logo in this navigation-bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530809/how-to-vertically-center-an-img-in-the-logo-in-this-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide `vertical-align: middle;` for `logo-text` class. If you are going for `inline-block` display, you have to set vertical alignment explicitly for each child.

```
.logo-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
* {
    background-color: #1B262C;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.logo {
    border: 3px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo-img {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
}

.logo-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 96px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header class="logo">
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-18/512/Facebook-2-512.png" alt="Sigma logo" class="logo-img">
    <h1 class="logo-text">Sigma</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` is a good solution for this type of problem. There is a good intro to flexbox over at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The specifics of why your current CSS *doesn't* work have to do with some other issues, including probably default CSS applied by your browser to elements of type `img` and `h1`. But, flexbox is widely supported by browsers, and is a good approach for situations like these.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `display: flex` for the alignment. Adding flex makes the `logo` class into a flex-container.

```
.logo{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center  
 justify-content: center
}

.logo-img {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    
}

.logo-text {
    font-size: 96px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```